How to Mock a Batch Response from an OData DataServiceContext
I am in the process of writing unit tests for a .NET FW 4.8 project that connects to an API using the OData.net library. The project uses a DataServiceContext to send batch requests and receive responses. To test this project, I am looking to mock the batch responses that are returned to the DataServiceContext.
I have transplanted some unit test code from the official OData.net Github repo, and I am able to mock responses for non-batched GET and PATCH requests, but I am having trouble mocking batch requests containing PATCH operations. Below is the working unit test that mocks the non-batched responses.
    [TestMethod]
    public void Update_Test()
    {
        DataServiceContext mockContext = new DataServiceContext(new Uri(Constants.BASE_URI));
        mockContext.Format.UseJson(Utils.BuildEdmModel());
        mockContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
    
        var salesOrdersQuery = mockContext.CreateQuery<MockSalesOrder>(Constants.SALES_ORDERS_SET_NAME);
    
        // Setup a GET request to fake
        string resp = Utils.LoadJsonPayload("GET_SalesOrderWithLineResp.json");
        Utils.MockQueryResponse(
            context: mockContext,
            baseUriStr: Constants.BASE_URI,
            entitySetName: Constants.SALES_ORDERS_SET_NAME,
            mockResponseValue: resp
        );

        // GET faked order, then update
        MockSalesOrder order = salesOrdersQuery.Expand(o => o.SalesOrderLines).First();
        order.OrderType = "Return";
        mockContext.UpdateObject(order);

        // Setup a PATCH request to fake
        resp = Utils.LoadJsonPayload("PATCH_SalesOrderWithLineResp.json");
        Utils.MockSaveResponse(
            context: mockContext,
            location: string.Format("{0}/SalesOrders(OrderNo='S-ORD100000',OrderType='Order')", Constants.BASE_URI),
            response: resp
        );

        // Fake a PATCH request
        mockContext.SaveChanges();
    }

The 'MockQueryResponse' and 'MockSaveResponse' methods were taken from the OData project and are defined as:
public static void MockQueryResponse(DataServiceContext context, string baseUriStr, string entitySetName, string mockResponseValue)
{
    string mockResponse = "{\"@odata.context\":\"" + baseUriStr + "/$metadata#" + entitySetName + "\",\"value\":" + mockResponseValue + "}";
    context.ResolveName = (type) => $"NS.{type.Name}";
    context.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnMessageCreating = (args) =>
    {
        var contentTypeHeader = "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8";
        var odataVersionHeader = "4.0";

        return new TestHttpWebRequestMessage(args,
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Content-Type", contentTypeHeader},
                {"OData-Version", odataVersionHeader},
            },
            () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mockResponse)));
    };
}

public static void MockSaveResponse(DataServiceContext context, string location, string response)
{
    context.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnMessageCreating = (args) =>
    {
        return new CustomizedRequestMessage(
            args,
            response,
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8"},
                { "Location", location },
            });
    };
}

For further reference, the mock GET response is defined as:
[
    {
        "OrderNo": "S-ORD100000",
        "OrderType": "Order",
        "SampleField": "Test",
        "SalesOrderLines": [
            {
                "OrderNo": "S-ORD100000",
                "OrderType": "Order",
                "LineNo": "1000",
                "SampleField": "Test"
            }
        ]
    }
]

and the mock PATCH response:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://mock.odata.service/$metadata#SalesOrders/$entity",
    "@odata.editLink": "http://https//mock.odata.service/SalesOrders(OrderNo='S-ORD100000',OrderType='Order')",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzE5OzY4MjIzMTYxNjY4MTkyNDY2MDgxazAwOyc=\"",
    "OrderNo": "S-ORD100000",
    "OrderType": "Order",
    "SampleField": "Test",
    "SalesOrderLines": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzE5OzY4MjIzMTYxNjY4MTkyNDY2MDgxOzAwOyc=\"",
            "OrderNo": "S-ORD100000",
            "OrderType": "Order",
            "LineNo": "1000",
            "SampleField": "Test"
        }
    ]
}

The previous code and responses work just fine, but if I update the response content to a batch response, and set the SaveChangeOptions in the SaveChanges call, I receive the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: The POST request expected a response with content. ID=14
at Microsoft.OData.Client.Error.ThrowBatchExpectedResponse(InternalError value)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.BatchSaveResult.<HandleBatchResponse>d__29.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.OData.Client.BatchSaveResult.HandleBatchResponseInternal(ODataBatchReader batchReader)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.BatchSaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()

The updated SaveChanges call for the batch request is:
mockContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithIndependentOperations | SaveChangesOptions.UseRelativeUri);

And the mock batch response:
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
                "odata-version": "4.0"
            },
            "body": {
                "@odata.context": "https://mock.odata.service/$metadata#SalesOrders/$entity",
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzE5OzczMTExMDYxMjE3NTYxMzY5MjkxOzAwOyc=\"",
                "OrderNo": "S-ORD100000",
                "OrderType": "Order",
                "SampleField": "Test"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I am stumped on the cause of this error. Any ideas or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
EDIT: (Alternative Solution)
The code I am writing unit tests for explicitly invokes a batch request using:
SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithIndependentOperations | SaveChangesOptions.UseRelativeUri);

This is the reason I had been looking into how I could mock the batch response. Upon further inspection, I realized I am not aiming to test a batch response specifically, but rather what the resulting entity states and errors are based on the response of the SaveChanges method call. It does not matter if I am sending a batch request or a series of requests using SaveChanges, the results of the method call are always serialized into the same return object. Based on this, I can utilize a standard SaveChanges call with no SaveChangeOptions specified, like in my original post.
In the method I am unit testing, I have moved the SaveChangeOptions out of the SaveChanges invocation, into a parameter overload so I may define these as needed for unit testing. Instead of mocking the batch response, I am now invoking the method with SaveChangeOptions.None and mocking the non-batch responses in a handler on a request-by-request basis.
The handler I am using now differs from the original post. I am using a MockHttpClientHandler as seen in this unit test defined in the OData.net library: Github - OData.net - DataServiceContextHttpClientHandlerProviderTests.cs
To handle response creation for different types of requests I have modified the request handler delegate to load a mock response from a json file based on the request's URI and HTTP operation.
I have found this handler to offer improved functionality as it offers a way to specify the HTTP status code in the response.
Handling requests and responses in this way allows me to test the functionality I need to. However, it does not answer my initial question of mocking batch responses. Therefore, I will leave the question open in case there is a potential solution for this.
